# Simplify NSDecimalNumber initialisation

Tags: objective-c, nsdecimalnumber

I have the following construct, which I would like to simplify. I had to use a NSString (?) in order to get rid of the NSNumber vs. NSDecimalNumber compiler Warning.

`NSDecimalNumber *ticksSinceSeventies = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[self timeIntervalSince1970]]];`

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: I realise this doesn't exactly answer your question, but why are you storing a double (NSTimeInteval) in an NSDecimalNumber; NSNumber is fine for doubles. NSNumber *ticksSinceSeventies = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[self timeIntervalSince1970]];

Comment: Dan is correct. NSDecimalNumber's use is for precise base-10 arithmetic. Since you are dealing with NSTimeIntervals, it's a safe assumption that you are dealing with dates, and there is a whole document dealing with [Calendrical Calculations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html)

Comment: @Daniel You guys should post an Answer otherwise I can't possibly resolve this thing and you don't get the props for it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only using `NSTimeInterval`s, which are doubles, then the base 10 arithmetic that `NSDecimalNumber` affords you isn't really necessary. You can just use `NSNumber` instead.

Your constructor would therefore just be:

```
NSNumber *ticksSinceSeventies = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[self timeIntervalSince1970]];
```

(assuming self is an `NSDate` subclass, or this is inside a category method).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[[self timeIntervalSince1970] stringValue]];
```

There may be ways to simplify it still better, but i am not aware.

Comment: This does not work:`typedef double NSTimeInterval;` therefore stringValue does not work

Comment: I thought your timeIntervalSince1970 is in NSNumber, when reading your "NSNumber vs NSDecimalNumber compiler warning".

Comment: Fair enough... I did get this compiler warning before when I tried to use an NSInteger.